# Bootstrap 5 ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm just finish install bootstrap 5 version `^5.0.0-alpha1` and import bootstrap in `app.js`

```
import "bootstrap"
```

**other.js**

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'));
myModal.show();
```

when I run the code it give me error **ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined**.

then I try to import bootstrap in **other.js** like this

```
import bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

but when I run `npm run dev` error **"export 'default' (imported as 'bootstrap') was not found in 'bootstrap'**

If Im import modal manually like `import { Modal } from "bootstrap"` it give me error **"TypeError: Illegal invocation"**

Answer (score 65):

If anyone trying to use with webpack, this solution worked for me.

```
window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js');
```

Comment: I wonder why this work but in bootstrap 5 docs there's no reference about this

Comment: Where do you put this line of code? In the script file for an individual web page? In the project level index file?

Comment: you put this app.js file. project level index file, generally where you define libraries like jquery, lodash etc.

Comment: Works in Ruby on Rails 6. Great.

Comment: Just this worked in rails 6 `window.bootstrap = require("bootstrap")` rails6 + webpacker + bootstrap 5

Comment: isn't this totally destroy the idea of modules?

Comment: True. It is not the concept based on modules. Like if you are working on React /Angular, you can follow @Kaliatech approach. But this approach is useful for backend rendered pages like using laravel.

Comment: works with bootstrap 5.1.3 - saved my day! :)

Comment: crazy that symfony documentation on webpack doesn't mention this.  They do mention you need to add `require('bootstrap');`, but not as a definition to window.  In fact, they do even worse by stating to use `const $ = require('jquery');` for jquery, but only `require('bootstrap');` for boostrap because "the bootstrap module doesn't export/return anything". https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html

Comment: This is the only one of the suggestions which worked for me when needing to use e.g. `bootstrap.modal` in inline HTML. A pure compiled JS solution would be better-off using e.g `import {Modal} from 'bootstrap';`

Answer (score 54):

If you use:

```
    import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'
```

then the syntax to use will be:

```
    let myModal = new Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'));
    myModal.show();
```

Working for me on a relatively simple setup with [Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite) and bootstrap-5.0.0-beta1.

Comment: Perfect! it works on Rails 6 and stimulusjs

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You just import the Component you need from `'bootstrap'` which is handled by webpack.

Comment: Perfectly work on Vue 3

Comment: That works even better than @alaksandar-jesus-gene 's solution because just Modal gets imported, not the whole library!

Answer (score 28):

Bootstrap 5.1 + webpack 5:

`app.js`

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
```

or if you only need Modal:

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.Modal = bootstrap.Modal;
```

and then you could use in `other.js` like:

```
var myModal = new Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'));
myModal.show();
```

Comment: window.bootstrap = bootstrap; helped me alot in getting bootstrap-select 1.14 beta3 with bootstrap 5. Nice one Patrick.

Comment: Thanks! `global.bootstrap = bootstrap` also worked.

Answer (score 8):

For me working

in app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 6):

in
`app.js`
after

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

insert this two line

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, you really helped me in my Laravel project.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by adding

```
<script type="module">
```

It worked
you can refer to it

Answer (score 3):

I tried the proposed solutions here and none of them worked for me. This is how I got it working using `react 18.2` and `bootstrap 5.2`.

1. install bootstrap using npm:
   `npm install bootstrap`
2. put this in your **App.js** to import the bootstrap CSS:
   `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`
3. include bootstrap JS like this:
   `import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'`

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 10 and Bootstrap 5.3

This worked for me:

```
import * as bootstrap from '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'
window.bootstrap = bootstrap
```

In the resources\js\app.js file.

Then in my other js file:

```
   var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'))
   myModal.show()
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's how to bundle Bootstrap 5 Javascript with only the plugins you need using Webpack:

**src/bootstrap-bundle-src.js**

```
import { Alert, Button, Collapse, Tooltip, Popover } from 'bootstrap'

window.bootstrap = {
    Alert, Button, Collapse, Tooltip, Popover
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bootstrap 5 custom Javascript bundler",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
  },
  "author": "You",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "exports-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/bootstrap-bundle-src.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bootstrap-bundle.min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            // Use babel for JS files
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            "@babel/preset-env"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

Then run **npm run build** to generate *dist/bootstrap-bundle.min.js*

Answer (score 1):

For **TypeError: Illegal Invocation** meaning:

```
var modal = new Modal(document.getElementById('modal'))

// no tag div with id modal
// will produce error **Illegal Invocation**
```

This work for me. `bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1`

```
<script>    
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap'

export default {
   data: () => ({
      modal: ''
   }),

   mounted() {
      this.modal = new Modal(document.getElementById('exampleModal'))
   },

   methods: {
      openModal() {
         this.modal.show()
      },

      closeModal() {
         this.modal.hide()
      }
   }
}
</script>

<template>
   <div id="exampleModal">...</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not import Bootstrap via a `<script>` tag or via CDN in your HTML, the `bootstrap` namespace is not on your window object, so it will not be defined. If you are using a bundler such as Webpack, you have to load it giving it the full name.

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js';
```

should work perfectly. This way, you will also have popper.js dependencies which are used by Bootstrap's JavaScript.

Make sure you actually are using something supporting ESnext.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel with Webpack this worked for me:

```
import {Collapse} from "bootstrap"
```

**Note: the parentheses**

```
let boostrapCollapse = new Collapse(searchPanel, {
    toggle: false
});
```