# How to hide Bootstrap 5 modal only on success?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, hide, bootstrap-5

Using bootstrap 5

I have a modal which I show when `#truck_modal` is clicked which works just fine like so:

(this code is at the top of my js file)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('#add_truck').addEventListener('click', AddTruck);

    const truck_modal = document.querySelector('#staticBackdrop');
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(truck_modal, {
        backdrop: 'static'
    });

    document.querySelector('#truck_modal').addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.show();
    });
})
```

Now, if I add the following to the above function it works.

```
document.querySelector('#add_truck').addEventListener('click', () => {
     modal.hide();
});
```

But here it runs when `#add_truck` is clicked regardless if the `AddTruck` function was successful or not, I only want it to hide if the `AddTruck` function is successful, so I tried the following.

```
function AddTruck() {

    ... some validations ...

    fetch('/inbound/add_truck', {
        
        ... some fetch code ...

    })
    .then(response => {
        jsonResponse = response.json();
        status_code = response.status;

        // console.log(jsonResponse);
        // console.log(status_code);

        if(status_code != 200) {
            alert('There was an error!');

        } else{
            origin.value = '';
            produce.value = '';
            license_num.value = '';
            loaded_weight.value = '';

            // document.querySelector('#add_truck').addEventListener('click', () => {
            //     modal.hide();
            // });
            modal.hide();
            // hideFunc();

            alert('Success!!!')
        }

        return status_code
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })

}
```

Even tried this:

```
function hideFunc() {
    const truck_modal = document.querySelector('#staticBackdrop');
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(truck_modal, {
        backdrop: 'static'
    });

    modal.hide();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help...

Or is this a feature?

### EDIT

These are my js, bootstrap and jquery scripts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{% static 'utils.js' %}"></script>
```

And I added `$('#truck_modal').modal('hide');` to the else block where I'm trying to hide it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had this problem too and sadly it was between chair and keyboard :(  (And maybe a little bit in not clearly written docs. Just to justify myself :) )

Your modal already exists. So calling:

```
function hideFunc() {
    const truck_modal = document.querySelector('#staticBackdrop');
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(truck_modal, {
        backdrop: 'static'
    });

    modal.hide();
}
```

Will not work, because by this you are creating new modal. So, you create a new modal, set its backdrop to static and then you hide it. Without even showing it.

Instead of creating a new one, you want to call / address the already existing one, by using bootstrap.Modal.getInstance. Like this:

```
function hideFunc() {
    const truck_modal = document.querySelector('#staticBackdrop');
    const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(truck_modal);    
    modal.hide();
}
```

This way you can make yourself custom Modal (Dropdown, Popover, ...) handlers. It is only briefly described in the documentation, so it is easy to overlook it.

Comment: `const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(truck_modal); modal.hide();` is absolutely what you are looking for if you've searched for this question online.

Comment: You can also use the function `Modal.getOrCreateInstance(truck_modal)` to get or get and create the modal instance.

Comment: saved my life. Thank you!

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm trying to do this on Vue. It says bootstrap is not defined. Any other way to do this?

Comment: @BalasubramanianS I have no experience with Vue js, but similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65385274/11863883

Comment: Thanks. I finally did a similar solution.

Comment: it seems that there is more than one such gasket between the chair and the monitor, and that's me

Answer (score 5):

To hide Bootstrap modal, use this code snippet

```
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById('myModalId'));
myModal.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @solilim answer,...

```
function hideModal(id) {
    const modal_el  = document.querySelector('#'+id);
    const modal_obj = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modal_el);

    if (modal_obj ==  null){
       return;
    }

   modal_obj.hide();
}

function showModal(id) {
    const modal_el  = document.querySelector('#'+id);
    let   modal_obj = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modal_el);

    if (modal_obj ==  null){
       modal_obj = new bootstrap.Modal(modal_el, {
        backdrop: 'static'
       });
   }

   modal_obj.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was actually very easy. Can't believe I spent two days on this... ‍♂️

I just sent the modal as a param to the `AddTruck` function like so:

```
document.querySelector('#add_truck').addEventListener('click', () => AddTruck(modal));
```

And then `modal.hide()` worked inside the `AddTruck` func.

Answer (score -7):

try this, it worked for me. I hide my modals using jquery

```
$('#truck_modal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: This doesn't work. And I think BS5 dropped jquery.

Comment: did you add the jquery script?
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

Comment: BS5 did not drop jquery I am currently using it. If scripts are added in the incorrect order it may cause issues

Comment: jquery loaded correctly without any errors, but the modal is still not being hidden

Comment: could paste the changes you made?

Comment: I pasted the changes as edit in the question

Comment: even if I included jquery it is not working