# How can I use Bootstrap 5 with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

After installing bootstrap with `npm install bootstrap` I added the style to `/pages/_app.js` like so:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

However anything from it that uses javascript does not work at all, e.g. the [Collapse example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/#example) from their docs.

```js
function App() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Link with href
          </a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Button with data-bs-target
          </button>
        </p>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <div class="card card-body">
            Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
export default App
```

If I add `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'` to `/pages/_app.js` then it starts "working" as expected, until a page reload in which it says `ReferenceError: document is not defined` [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hAn0.png), which leads me to believe it's not possible or that I shouldn't try to use boostrap + react or next.js.
I had thought them dropping jquery meant that it should work just "out of the box" with frameworks like react (as in not needing react-boostrap or reactstrap anymore)

Is there a way to properly use boostrap 5 and nextjs? Or should I just try something else entirely or go back to using reactstrap (which currently seems to only support boostrap 4)?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use Bootstrap 5 from Angular, Next and ReactJS.  And no, it has nothing to do with "dropping jQuery" (although I happen to LOVE jQuery!) Look here for several solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65260998/421195.  Please post back what worked for you!

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for reply, my line of thinking that it's not possible to use comes from seeing multiple posts saying it's dumb to use bootstrap and react and that you should use material ui instead. But since I know bootstrap I want to try use it if it's possible.  As for the question you linked, none of that worked for me. I still get "document is not defined" or if I use the top answer I get "window is not defined"

Comment: https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrap-5-in-next-js/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a common thing that most of us miss while switching to NextJS.

**Problem:** Document is not defined.

**Reason:** NextJS renders your app at server, and there is no window, document etc. on  server, hence `document` is not defined. you can even `console.log(typeof window, typeof document)` to verify this.

[image]

**NOW, what is the solution?**

I used this code in my function component:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        typeof document !== undefined ? require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap') : null
    }, [])
```

`useEffect` with empty `dependencies` works like `componentDidMount()` which runs after the code is run second time.
Since code runs first at server and ***then*** at client, it will not produce errors, as client has document.

> I've never used `componentDidMount(), ever.

**Did that worked for me?**

I just copied your `Collapse example` in my other app to verify this.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. Although for mine I had to add `import { useEffect } from 'react'`(else useeffect was undefined)  at the top which I notice you don't have , is that correct? This is my entire `/pages/_app.js` now https://pastebin.com/raw/2qbEMxXp

Comment: @DavidPH Excellent! Your pastebin code worked right away, except that in my default Next.js app global.css is spelled '../styles/globals.css'. -  I was also required to install popper for it to work: `yarn add @popperjs/core`

Answer (score 2):

Steps:
1- Install bootstrap through npm.
2- now add bootstrap in _app.js.

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../styles/global.scss';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    import("jquery/dist/jquery.min.js");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    typeof document !== undefined ? require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap') : null
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe React Bootstrap (beta as of July 2021) now supports Bootstrap5: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/    See image from their website:

[image: From their website]

Answer (score 0):

the _app.js and _app.tsx are difference

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  // import bootstrap-js-libs below for _app.js
  useEffect(() => {
     import("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap");
   }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    typeof document !== undefined ? require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap") : null;
  }, []);
```

We can use CDN on _document file too!

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, The easiest way to use bootstrap is to include a CDN link.

**Syntax:**

```html
export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        
<!-- CDN Link -->
<link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />




      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

**here is a project i am working on:**

[image: code]

**Its Output:(bootstrap button)**

[image: output]

Answer (score -2):

You only imported bootstrap.css, you must import bootstrap's js file if you want to use collapse. And bootstrap's js require jquery and popper. However, react or nextjs doesn't recommend you to use jquery.

You can use one of 2 below libs alternative:

1. [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)
2. [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

For latest bootstrap 5, you can use BootstrapCDN:

In _document.js, add 2 lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Normally I'd say I appreciate any reply but it's as if you didn't read the question. 1) I'm showing how I'm attempting to import bootstrap's js and failing. 2) I'm asking about bootstrap 5, and react-bootstrap + reactstrap are for bootstrap 4, 3) I mentioned those in my post anyway, 4) bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jquery