# ReferenceError: document is not defined NextJS TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

Import trace for requested module:
./app/StarrySky.tsx
./app/resume/page.tsx
✓ Compiled in 425ms (711 modules)
⨯ app\StarrySky.tsx (9:4) @ document
⨯ ReferenceError: document is not defined

const vw = Math.max( document?.documentElement?.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0);

Full code : https://codeshare.io/X87QAM

Comment: Hi i just ran your code on my own without changes and work fine. I would like to say in next 13 how ssr is default and you cant use document on your server component.  Although you can mark your component as client using 'use client' at the start and then should work. Thing that I already saw in your code

Comment: Oh I just saw the error on my console. Server side error

Comment: hi, do you have a solution

Comment: yeah, try the answer

Answer (score 0):

That is happen because document is being called on the server.

To fix it you can desactivate the preload on the server using a dynamic call

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const StarrySky = dynamic(() => import("@/app/components/starry-sky"), {
  ssr: false,
});

export default function Home() {
  return <StarrySky />;
}
```

Note that I move all the code to other component, just to simplify the answer. it was a copy and paste.

You probably could also do a check if document exist (and also window) and try to fix it in that way I did a try and fix the issue but the beheviour was not correct.

You can check this answer with good references to your problem [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386843/nextjs-referrenceerror-document-is-not-defined)

Also this is the link to next/dynamics [next/dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading)